How to get video Mono<Resource> from backend on frontend and bind to video tag on Vue?
I have video endpoint on backend,
@GetMapping(value = "/{fileName}/stream", produces = "video/mp4")
    public Mono<Resource> lessonVideoStream(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        return this.streamingService.getVideo(fileName);
    }

it return a video stream, that allow you to watch video while video loading. And when i past this video in video tag on my VUE frontend everything works. But i have jwt token auth, and i need to send Authorization header with baerer to my API.
I expect to my frontend on Vue will send authorization token every time that it send get request on my video
